# Putting widgets into boxes (Npyscreen)

Tags: python, npyscreen

The problem with this code is that when navigating the interface, the boxes come to the foreground and cover the widgets. Is it possible to put widgets in boxes?

```
class MainForm(npyscreen.ActionFormV2):
    def create(self):
        # Виджет для ввода времени
        self.time_widget_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxTitle, relx=0, rely=0, max_width=76, max_height=4)
        self.time_widget_box.name = "Время прогноза"
        text_widget_time = self.add(npyscreen.Textfield, value="Выберите час:", max_width=35, relx=2, rely=2, editable=False)
        self.time_widget_box.entry_widget = text_widget_time

        self.time_widget = self.add(npyscreen.Textfield, value="00", max_width=35, relx=38, rely=2, editable=True)
        self.selected_time_field = self.time_widget
        self.selected_time_field.add_handlers({curses.KEY_LEFT: self.move_hour_left, curses.KEY_RIGHT: self.move_hour_right})

        # Виджет "Запросы"
        self.remaining_requests_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxTitle, relx=76, rely=0, max_width=41, max_height=4)
        self.remaining_requests_box.name = "Запросы"
        text_widget = self.add(npyscreen.Textfield, value="Количество оставшихся запросов: ", rely=2, relx=78, editable=False)
        self.remaining_requests_box.entry_widget = text_widget
        
        # Виджет для ввода дня
        self.day_widget = self.add(npyscreen.BoxBasic,rely=4,relx=0,max_width=35,max_height=8)
        self.day_widget = self.add(npyscreen.TitleSelectOne,max_height=2, max_width=30, value=[0], name="День:", values=["Сегодня", "Завтра"],rely=6,relx=2,scroll_exit=True)
        
        # Виджет для ввода города
        self.city_widget_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxTitle, name="Город:", rely=4, relx=36, max_width=80, max_height=4)
        self.city_widget = self.add(npyscreen.Textfield, rely=6, relx=38, max_width=40, max_height=4)
        self.city_widget.add_handlers({curses.ascii.NL: self.on_enter_button_pressed_city_widget})
        self.city_widget_box.entry_widget = self.city_widget
        
        # Виджет для отображения данных о погоде
        self.weather_widget_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxBasic, rely=8, relx=36, max_width=80, max_height=20)
        self.weather_widget = self.add(npyscreen.MultiLineEdit, value="", rely=9,relx=37,max_width=76,max_height=16)

        # Инициализация переменных для отображения статуса запроса, ошибки и данных о погоде
        self.request_count = 0
        self.status_widget_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxBasic, name="Статус запроса:", rely=12,relx=0,max_width=35,max_height=8)
        self.status_widget = self.add(npyscreen.MultiLineEdit, value="", rely=13,relx=1,max_width=33,max_height=6)
        self.error_widget_box = self.add(npyscreen.BoxBasic, value="", name="Ошибка:", rely=20,relx=0,max_width=35,max_height=8)
        self.error_widget = self.add(npyscreen.MultiLineEdit, value="", rely=21, relx=1, max_width=33,max_height=6)
```

I tried to use "entry_widget", but this didn't solve the problem.